# Formatting php $_POST for document printing

Tags: php, forms, post, formatting, printing

Im trying to make a html form processed in php that outputs to pdf and is print ready.

This is what I have:

A page requesting the categories to include

A page which presents text areas for that categories

A page which displays the final result with an option to print and or make a pdf.

I can make all the information pass along the pages what im lacking is way to display the content properly formatted.

I need this layout:

```
Text here bold: Description of item
                Description of item
     (precisely one empty line)
Some more bold text: Description of item
                     Description of item
```

and so on.

Im a bit stumbled since the Item descriptions are coming from text areas of which I am able to preserve the line breaks by echoing <.pre> (please excuse the dot, i dont understand how to escape the tag ;) tags along, which end up including all the white space due to the textarea cols.

Assuming I have two textareas and two variables with the titles posting to the last page, how would i go about formatting it properly?

Thank you.

-----EDIT-------

To clarify what I intend:

I have 3 pages:

1 one:

```
<div class="menu">
Por favor seleccione os conteúdos:
<form name="Categorias" action="Elementos_Descritivos.php" method="post">
<div class="cb-row">
    <label for="nome">Nome:</label>
    <input id="nome" name="Nome" type="checkbox" value="Nome" checked />
</div>
<div class="cb-row">
    <label for="data">Data:</label>
    <input id="data" name="Data" type="checkbox" value="Data" checked />
</div>
<div class="cb-row">
    <label for="cliente">Cliente:</label>
    <input id="cliente" name="Cliente" type="checkbox" value="Cliente" checked />
</div>
<div class="cb-row">
    <label for="ob">Observações:</label>
    <input id="ob" name="Observacoes" type="checkbox" value="Observacoes" checked />
</div>
<div class="submit">
    <input type="submit" value="Seguinte" />
</div>
    </form>
</div>
</div>
```

In this one you choose wich categories go into the doc.

Page 2:

```
<body>
<?php 

$Nome = $_POST["Nome"]; 
$Data = $_POST["Data"]; 
$Cliente = $_POST["Cliente"]; 
$Observacoes = $_POST["Observacoes"];

$Nome1 = "Nome";
$Data1 = "Data";
$Cliente1 = "Cliente";
 $Observacoes1 = "Observacoes";


echo "<div class=\"menu2\">
      <form name=\"Detalhes\" action=\"Pre_Impressao.php\" method=\"post\">
      Por favor preencha os todos os campos em branco:<br/><br/>";

 #######################################_NOME_######################################

if ( $Nome == $Nome1 ) {

echo "<div> Nome: <textarea name=\"Nome\" rows=\"6\" cols=\"60\"></textarea></div>    <br/>";
}

########################################_DATA_#####################################

if ( $Data == $Data1 ) {

echo "<div> Data: <textarea name=\"Data\" rows=\"6\" cols=\"60\"></textarea></div><br/>";
}

 ########################################_CLIENTE_##################################

 if ( $Cliente == $Cliente1 ) {

echo "<div> Cliente: <textarea name=\"Cliente\" rows=\"6\" cols=\"60\"></textarea></div>    <br/>";
}

#######################################_OBSERVACOES_###############################

 if ( $Observacoes == $Observacoes1 ) {

 echo "<div> Observacoes: <textarea name=\"Observacoes\" rows=\"6\" cols=\"60\"></textarea></div><br/>";
 }
 ####################################################################################

 echo "<div class=\"submit\">
      <input type=\"submit\" value=\"Seguinte\" />
        </div>
     </form>
       </div>

?>
```

The second page displays text areas for filling information about hte categories selected in the previous page.

And then page 3, which ought to display the inputs nicely formatted, that's were im stumbled, I know my php is hideous, and i would be better off with a for each loop but for now im trying to focus on getting it done rather than getting it done in a better way :)

If im still not being clear in any aspect please let me clarify so i can improve the post.

Thanks.

Comment: I don't really understand your question... can you give an example on how your data structure actually looks like (e.g. with print_r($data); )?

Answer (score 0):

You can put PHP code inside normal HTML code (or PDF code), but it might be easier to iterate and generate this way:

Comment: Thank you, thats is way I should consider, but my main issue inst displaying but ratter formatting it properly, im finding it incredibly hard to display the content in the way I need wich is a simple one ;)

Answer (score 0):

If I remember correctly, you can put your data in a table and the formatting will render properly in a PDF.  I have also come across the issue that some CSS properties do not render properly in PDF.  Hope that helps.

Comment: I was hoping to get the raw data and neatly format it with css, ill check on pdf compatibility issues. Thank you.